# How to count for each tuple, the number of strictly greater tuples in an array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, counting

Let's say you have a `Pair` class with variable `a` and `b`.

A `Pair` object is "strictly greater" than another when both of its `a` and `b` values are greater than the other one's. For example, (3,4) would be greater than (2,3), but (3,5) is not greater than (4,4) and so on.

Given an array of `Pair`, what is the best way to count the number of stricly greater `Pair` for each of the element in the array? I can solve this within n^2, but I don't think this would be the most optimal answer.

Comment: The question is unclear. Would (3, 4) be greater than (2, 3)? Or do each a and b of the greater Pair need to be greater than *both* the a and b of the smaller Pair, as in (3, 4) > (1, 2)?

Comment: Hi, I made the clairification within the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the `Pair`s based on their `a` variable; this will take `O(nlogn)` time. Then construct a segment tree using some self-balancing binary tree structure (red-black, AVL, etc.) from your pairs, with the `b` variable as its key, and the size of the node's subtree as its value. This too will take `O(nlogn)` time.

Now, iterate over your sorted array of `Pair`s. For each pair, first locate the corresponding node in the segment tree, and calculate the total number of `Pair`s with larger `b` from this node and its ancestors' values/sizes. Add this to a running sum, and remove the node from the tree. This should take `O(logn)` time per `Pair`. Continue this process for all the other `Pair`s in the array. At the end, your running sum will represent the total count of strictly greater objects in the array, in `O(nlogn)` time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort with `O(n*logn)` and a simple min-max decision with `O(n)`, the solution max `O(n*logn)`.

But the OP question is not clear, the sorting maybe impossible. Partial orders may.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116022/can-a-complex-number-ever-be-considered-bigger-or-smaller-than-a-real-number

```
class Pair<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Pair<T>> {

    private final T a;
    private final T b;
    private final T max;
    private final T min;

    /**
     * @param i
     * @param j
     */
    public Pair(final T a, final T b) {

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        if (0 < a.compareTo(b)) {
            this.max = a;
            this.min = b;
        } else {
            this.max = b;
            this.min = a;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Pair<T> o) {

        // you can skip it if equals(...) is hard
        if (this == o || this.a.equals(o.a) && this.b.equals(o.b)) {
            return 0;
        }

        // because strictly greater
        return this.min.compareTo(o.max);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how would this algorithm solves cases like (3,5) and (4,4) where neither is strictly greater than another?

Comment: You asks strict greater only. Basically the two dimensional numbers are not comparable, please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116022/can-a-complex-number-ever-be-considered-bigger-or-smaller-than-a-real-number

Comment: I'm not trying to compare the pair where the strictly greater cases don't apply, what I mean is that with your sort algorithm how do you actually count the number of strictly greater `Pair` for each element in the sorted array in O(n) time?

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this with an augmented balanced binary tree and without a segment tree by first sorting the list on one of the variables, say `b`. We then have:

```
[(a_i, b_0), (a_i, b_1), (a_i, b_2)..., (a_i, b_n)]
```

Now the problem becomes: for each `a`, count the number of greater `a`s on the right, for which there are [known O(n log n) solutions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-smaller-elements-on-right-side/), iterating from the right and inserting the `a`s into an augmented balanced binary tree. Care must be taken not to count elements where one of the variables is equal rather than greater.

Answer (score 0):

- Lets say the pairs are like these : [(1,2) (1,4) (3,5) (2,7) (4,6)]
- Now sort these, in O(nlogn) time, on the basis of X co-ordinate.
- The array looks like (I'm just writing x and y values separately for visualization) :

  x values = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
  y values = [2, 4, 7, 5, 6]
- Now create a new array RightMax for y values. RightMax = [7, 7, 6, 6]
- If for any element, RightMax[i]<=yValues[i] the i'th pair will be in the answer. If RightMax[i] > yValues[i], won't be in the answer.